# scilab_SIVP atomsload error

Tags: scilab

I am facing a problem in loading SIVP toolbox in Scilab console. I am using scilab 5.5.0.I have installed libtiff4. I am getting the following error. Can anyone please help?

```
SIVP - Scilab Image and Video Processing Toolbox
Load macros
Load gateways
atomsLoad: An error occurred while loading 'SIVP-0.5.3.1-2':
link: The shared archive was not loaded: libtiff.so.4: cannot open shared object file:      No such file or directory
 !--error 10000 

at line     335 of function atomsLoad called by :  
atomsLoad SIVP
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I am using Fedora 20. Navigate to your lib folder and check to see if you have libtiff.so.4, you probably don't have this file or else you wouldn't get this error. However, you may have libtiff.so.5 or .3. If you have the older one just install .4 by installing openCV. If you have .5 then you'll have to create a symbolic link like 
`sudo -c 'ln -s libtiff.so.5 libtiff.so.4`

This solves the problem in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have libtiff?

If not and you are running Ubuntu use

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff4
```